# Обойти типизированный объект

Tags: typescript

Есть ли методы обхода типизированных объектов в `TypeScript`?

```
var arr: {[key: number]: string};
```

Comment: а чем вам обычный обход объекта не угодил?

Comment: @ThisMan, при обходе при помощи `for-in` переменная может быть либо `string`, либо, `any`. Интересует, есть ли возможность такого обхода, при котором тип элемента будет сохраняться? Например, если элементы объекта - это объекты классов.

Comment: С чего бы? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQEMBOmBciDeA2gNYCmAnnmCALYBGpmAungM5SYxgDmAvgJQEAUIkQAbUlESZSrRAF5EAciUBuEYmBxMiVBKnFEXRFkyD8G0RATtEANwUnsJJqsQB6d4ijkADqXsFeUV2Th5LaVlEAGpFO3VRXg0ZKBBMJBlWdV4gA

Comment: @AlexeyTen, при объявлении `let k in arr` переменная `k`, разве, будет не `any`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я почему-то думал, что параметр в `for-in` - это значение, а это ключ. То есть, можно брать `string`, даже если ключи в массиве `number`, и далее уже обращаться как `obj[k]`, тогда тип будет учитываться.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => { const val = obj[key as any] })`